# Is the "inlining videos" capability turned off on this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I have just edited a new post, [Help understanding bridge settings](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4153/help-understanding-bridge-settings), so that the video would be "inlined" and playable in the post itself<sup>1</sup>.

However, the video does not show up, and only the raw link (`https://youtu.be/HaeCBru3mOI`) is displayed:

> [image: Only raw link is visible]

This is the markup:

> [image: Markup of post]

I have used the *same* markup method, for inlining the video clip as this post, [Is ATC communication subject to FCC profanity regulations?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/is-atc-communication-subject-to-fcc-profanity-regulations), on SE.Aviation:

> [image: Markup on SE.Aviation]

and there the video clip is inlined:

> [image: Post on SE.Aviation showing inline video clip]

---

#### TL;DR

Is video inlining disabled on SE.3D Printing, or is it because we are still beta?

If it can be enabled , then should/could it be enabled?

I personally think it would be useful to enable it, and save a few mouse clicks (and RSI) having to open the video in another tab/window etc. What do other people think?

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Allow embedded HTML5 YouTube video](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121209/allow-embedded-html5-youtube-video?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might have something to do with this site still being in Beta. Again, not sure though.

Comment: Good question, I lumped this into a more [general question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta) and posted it on the Meta.StackExchange.

Comment: @tbm0115 - appears that it just needs to be enabled, according to Markshancock's answer below. The question is, now, I suppose, do we really need it? There are a number of questions appearing that include videos of people's issues, where the video will much more easily describe the issue, than a written description. "A video is worth a million words", so to speak...

Comment: Perhaps with regards to maintenance answers or troubleshooting print questions. Might need a separate discussion in Meta.

Comment: @tbm0115 - done, see [Should we turn on “inlined video”?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/should-we-turn-on-inlined-video)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per answer to [What are the limitations in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta)

"Inline videos is a feature that is off by default on all sites and only turned on if the community thinks it's necessary to improve the quality of a good portion of their question base."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think on this site it would be useful - but we need to be fairly aggressive about closing questions that don't have a fully readable 'text' question. The video must only be for clarification, not as a replacement for writing a question.

Answer (score 0):

A note of caution, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/257#answer-261) on the Stack Moderators site, Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2's post, [How do you request embedded video for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/257) - As mods can only follow these links I've included the content below:

> I don't know how exactly to request it, but I do want to point at one
>   pretty big downside.
>
> **The player is pretty darn big.** Plus, my experience is that it has a tendency to eat CPU cycles for breakfast.
>
> I looked at the numbers [about a year ago over on Space Exploration
>   Meta](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/883/are-there-ways-to-make-posts-with-images-better-for-low-connect-speed-users-doe/885#comment3547_885).
>   What I found was:
>
> > Loading https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21891/415 without using the browser cache downloads 7642 KB for me just now. Of that,
> >     `www.youtube.com` is responsible for 3182 KB and `i.stack.imgur.com`
> >     another 2729 KB. Excluding just the embedded images and the
> >     video-related downloads leaves about 1.7 MB to be downloaded. That's
> >     still a sizable chunk of data for what basically amounts to a few
> >     pages of text, but not quite as extreme as 7.6 MB.
>
> So one video embed adds about 3 MB download for everyone viewing the
>   post, regardless of whether or not they are in any way interested in
>   the video. (I think the video itself is downloaded on demand, so if
>   someone actually watches the video, that adds even more data, but at
>   that point at least they have some interest in it.) In situations
>   where connections are metered by the megabyte, this can add up
>   quickly, and is something that should be kept in mind before turning
>   on this feature. Not everyone is on a fast,
>   no-extra-charge-per-megabyte connection.
>
> (Yes, I'm big on keeping text as mostly text. I'm old-fashioned in
>   that regard.)

Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/257#answer-260):

> > Are there any downsides to having embedded video (performance or otherwise)?
>
> Yep, [performance could be an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279637/295232). Also, malicious users could post links to videos with ... questionable ... content (though this could be alleviated by requiring some reputation to post embedded videos, just as some sites do with pictures).